# How to prove that $P(X = x-1) \cdot P(X=x+1) \le (P(X=x))^2$ for a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Using Poisson distribution, i need to prove that

$$P(X = x-1)\cdot P(X=x+1) \le (P(X=x))^2$$

How do i prove that this is true?

Comment: ¿What have you tried? ¿Where are you stuck? Please add these details to your question.

Comment: Why don't you type this short inequality instead of referring to an image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $X\sim Poisson(\lambda)$. Then

$P(X=x-1)P(X=x+1)=\frac{\lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda}}{(x-1)!} \frac{\lambda^{x+1}e^{-\lambda}}{(x+1)!}=\frac{\lambda^{2x}e^{-2\lambda}}{(x-1)!(x+1)!}$.

Comment: tnks in advance, best regards

Comment: log-concavity property of Poisson distribution...